# jssor slideshow and changing options on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jssor slideshow and i need to change the slide option passed to the slider and my problem seem to be that the slideshow is intialized with the default options and i cant change them since its alrdy intialized  am trying to change the option when the window is resized to a specfic width ... its currently taking the new options when i refresh the page but i need the options to change when i resize the window  . is there anyway to triger the intialize event again so it can change the slider options?

Comment: I guess re-initialization is not reasonable. There are some apis enable you do something after initialization. http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-api.html